# Handle confusable characters In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have a column in SQL Server with data as shown below  :

Column1

```
AUDIDOO                                                               
ABC123            
Abc456            
Abc578            
ABC021
```

And we have created a procedure in that we fetching data based on this column like as below

```
select * 
from Table1
where Column1 = @InputColumn1
```

But if we pass any one of the input from below combination we should get `AUDIDOO` as Result.

```
AUDIDOO      
AUD1D00     
AUDID00    
AUD1DOO        
AUDIDO0     
AUDID0O     
AUD1DO0      
AUD1D0O
```

Please advice the query/proc/fun in SQL Server

Comment: I am confused, `AUD1D00` there are `zero's` in the end of the string, and `AUDIDOO` contain alphabet `O` in the end. How they both are same.

Comment: unfortunately your question isn't very clear but you could use IF/ELSE to set the paramter to AUDIDOO when some of the other inputs come in.

Comment: Are there other examples you can show us besides `AUDIDOO`?  Is there a general rule for replacement/sounding similar?

Comment: But that is the our requirement.zeros or 'O' are same.

Comment: i,1,0,o -- are confusable characters . if any one of the letter comes in input we need to generate Combinations and fetch data from table using this combinations

Comment: I don't know why you want to achieve this, can you explain what is your scenario for which you need this.

Comment: @DarkRob In the old days of typewriters there wasn't a `zero` key so it was usual to use the small letter `o` instead. A lot of users bring that habit over to computer keyboards. That way you often end up with data like `1o` instead of `10`. OP might want to clean up such mess.

Comment: @DarkRob some systems are also defined like that. For example chassisnumber of vehicles dont allow confusing characters, but unfortunate some system still allow typing them. IMHO it is better to replace then when inserting/updating in your table, so you dont have any of that mess in your table

Comment: Updating the table is one of the option but if client treat some more charcters as confusing bucket we need to update entire table .As of now 1/i or 0/o ,in future D/0 or 8/S may add.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Use replace to convert all your possible combination of values into one value.
Here the key is you cannot change the behavior of string value for `O` or `0`. So it's better to come on some common ground where all `O` is either `0` or vice versa. After that when you are performing any operation then you know that there are only one character which you set by using `replace`.

Sample code is there.

```
declare @tab table  ( col varchar(100) )

insert into @tab ( col )
values ( 'AUDIDOO' )
, ( 'ABC123' )
, ( 'Abc456' )
, ( 'Abc578' )
, ( 'AUDID00' )

declare @col varchar(10) 
set @col = 'AUDIDoo'

--- here replace all '0' with 'O' or vice versa in both the statement to get the result
select * from @tab where 
replace(replace(col,'0','O'),'1', 'i') = replace(replace(@col,'0','O'),'1', 'i')
```

In general it is not possible what you have experienced and explained in your question.
There is a clear difference between `O` and `0` in any language.

Below is an example to explain:

```
declare @tab table  ( col varchar(100) )

insert into @tab ( col )
  values ( 'AUDIDOO' )
  , ( 'ABC123' )
  , ( 'Abc456' )
  , ( 'Abc578' )
  , ( 'ABC021' )

declare @col varchar(10) 
set @col = 'AUDIDOO'

select * from @tab where col = @col

Result
-------------
AUDIDOO


set @col = 'AUD1D00'
select * from @tab where col = @col

Result
-------------
---- blank
```

There must be something missing at your end.

SQL is not case sensitive so if you are entering `O` or `o`, they are same. At least they both are alphabet so for a case you can say yes they are similar.

But `O` is alphabet and `0` is numeric, they are not same. And there is no logic to compare them and get the result as same.

Comment: But if we pass AUDIDoo also need to fetch same results

Comment: i,1 and o,0 -- These are confusable characters , we will get any one of the letter in input but we need to fetch same result.we need to treat i=1 and o=0 if it occures in same position

Comment: For example : ABC123 in our table but input comes as ABCi23 ,we need to showtheresult : ABC123

Comment: `These are confusable characters`, confusable to whom??? I don't want to offend you....but think once, how they are confusable.

Comment: If we capture a photo in that content is  ABCi23  but due to poor quality picture ,it may visible as ABC123 ,But in our table data is ABCi23 .so if they pass input As ABC123 we need to show the result ABCi23 ,that is the requirement

Comment: @dharmatej: Edited my ans for your case, and I think that will surely work.

Comment: Thank you.We tried using replace and we tried second option also (inserting/updatting) but as of now 1/i and 0/o are letters ,if some more charactes (like D/0 etc) may add in future ,so we need to update entire table .that is risky.And also we try to generate all possible cobinations and used in filter condition. Example : ABC120 is input,we are generating ABCi20,abci20,abc120,abc12o like that and all combination used in where cluass

Comment: @dharmatej: no i am not suggesting to edit your record, this is just for DDL statement. Because `i` or `1` which is correct is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to search like this, you could use the replace function.
But mind you, this will not perform well

```
select t.* 
from   Table1 t
where  replace(replace(t.Column1, 'I', '1'), 'o', '0') = replace(replace(@InputColumn1, 'I', '1'), 'o', '0')
```

In my opinion this is not the best way to handle this.

I solved this by not allowing confusing characters in my table at all
When inserting/updating I replace `o by zero` and `i by 1` so I have no confusing characters at all in my table.

This can be done by your client, or by a trigger on the table.

Comment: Thank you.We tried using replace  and we tried second option also (inserting/updatting) but as of now 1/i and 0/o are letters ,if some more charactes (like D/0 etc)  may add in future  ,so we need to update entire table .that is risky

Comment: And also we try to generate all possible cobinations and used in filter condition. Example : ABC120 is input,we are generating ABCi20,abci20,abc120,abc12o like that and all combination used in where cluass

Comment: well if more confusing characters can exists, you need to add extra `replace` functions in your `where` clause. I know its not ideal, and it can affect performance, but I dont really see another way to handle this

Comment: Using the `replace` function seems like the best option for you then, because it will not change any data in your table, and is easy to maintain if additional confusing characters start showing up

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.Column1) AS RId,
    x.*
    INTO #Table1
FROM
(   
    SELECT 'AUDIDOO' AS Column1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC123' UNION ALL            
    SELECT 'Abc456' UNION ALL            
    SELECT 'Abc578' UNION ALL            
    SELECT 'ABC021' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AUD1D00' UNION ALL     
    SELECT 'AUDID00' UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'AUD1DOO' UNION ALL        
    SELECT 'AUDIDO0' UNION ALL     
    SELECT 'AUDID0O' UNION ALL     
    SELECT 'AUD1DO0' UNION ALL      
    SELECT 'AUD1D0O' UNION ALL      
    SELECT 'AUD2Djj' UNION ALL      
    SELECT 'AUD7Dpp'  
) x

DECLARE @InputCol1 VARCHAR(10)

--SELECT @InputCol1 = 'AUDIDOO';
SELECT @InputCol1 = 'AUD_D__';

SELECT 
    * 
FROM #Table1 t 
WHERE t.Column1 LIKE @InputCol1;

DROP TABLE #Table1;
```

Explanation: Please replace _ (underscore) with character value whichever you want any character.
e.g.: AUD***[1,I,2,7]***D***[0,O,j,p][0,O,j,p]***